# Can I learn enough basics using SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

Where I work, they use SharePoint Enterprise, and it's obviously on a secure network. I am being tasked with creating a document library, and I can do enough to 'get by' but I want to actually become proficient enough with SharePoint to be an Admin there (they don't currently have one). Now, I know I'm a LONG way from being close to the level a lot of you folks are, so my question is that if I install SharePoint Online, will that give me enough of an environment to learn many of the basics to 'get by' *better* when I get back to work? I'm going to be using a lot of Lynda.com training and am currently looking for courses that my company will pay for to really help me advance in learning SharePoint. If anyone has any suggestions or advice on the best way to go about this, I would be extremely indebted to you!

Thank you!

Will

Comment: I can see your point. My question was asking if I can learn the basics using the ONLINE version of SharePoint. I realize that the packages are different in Foundation, Server and Server Enterprise vice ONLINE. The basics of SharePoint, which I intended to mean files, folders, libraries, and setting permissions, was all I was after to start. I want to learn more, yes, but all I've got available to me is ONLINE because I don't want to make a large money commitment doing all this from home. I apologize for not forming the question to be without a doubt fact-based, but it was answered well. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can relate to this question because I was in the same place as yours two years back, the only difference being I had no clue where to start, so I started with Google.

For you, I have two suggestions (apart from online education videos, of course):

1. Get to learn every article in SharePoint's "Plan for ---" and "Configure ---".

   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261834.aspx
   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262957.aspx

When you open the articles, you might be a bit overwhelmed by the amount of content there, but I believe there are no shortcuts with SharePoint. You should know it inside out.

2. As you will read along there will be many features that you don't know about, and there comes the help from online courses. Search for specific topics, look at the videos for 15-20 minutes and jump back to your articles.

Now you will not get all the configurations on Office365 that are there with on-prem, however as you go through the articles Microsoft does explain the differences and/or workarounds.

**Note**: The reason for my disliking towards online courses is that they cover a small well-known segment of SharePoint very well, but when it comes to advanced features you need to know your way around on MSDN. Please correct me if anyone has had a different experience.

Comment: There is a LOT of information on that link, as you said, but I think that it's going to be extremely helpful to me in the long-term. SharePoint is a huge learning curve compared to the other MS products I'm familiar with, but I'm starting to get it now, with ribbons only being available depending on where you're clicking. Now I just have to put everything together, get some document libraries configured, and get comfortable with websites, libraries, and lists that I'm able to create. Once I'm better, I can move on to the more advanced things. Definitely not just a weekend project! Thanks much!

Answer (score 2):

If you are pretty new to SharePoint, then yes, SharePoint Online will help you to get started, particularly if your focus initially is on using the "everyday" aspects of SharePoint, such as document libraries, lists, pages, web parts, workflows, content types, views etc.

If you have admin rights in a SharePoint Online/Office 365 environment, you can also get to know the basics of some of the more administrative functions like term store/managed metadata, search, user profiles, business connectivity services.

However if you're goal is to become an admin for an on-prem SharePoint farm, you'll need to be aware that there are major differences in what you can do on-prem vs online.

Once you've got the basics and done some training, setting up a test farm for yourself that you can use to learn further would be my goal.

Comment: I think you are missing a very basic point here. Will is looking at an Admin role and not a developer role. Your first para is entirely developer centric, and second one too lands in the developer zone, while you miss to cover the most important tasks of an Admin.